# DynamicAdvisedInterceptor intercept (UserService.save throws java.lang.Exception)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have error message on server. 
I tried to debug this:

userService.save(user);

And pressed "F7". Instead of body of method "save", programm goes to "CglibAopProxy.class" to class "DynamicAdvisedInterceptor" method "intercept".  In debugger log a see: "UserService.save throws java.lang.Exception".

My question is, why programm not going to body of method save, or not throw NullPointerException?

I'm using Transactional annotation. Maybe problem with it.

Comment: Because you are in a proxy, and when debugging it simply follows the call flow. Which first goes to a proxy, 0 or more interceptors and then to the actual object.

Comment: ok, i set brakepoint inside body of method "save". And it really goes to it by pressing "F9". But it's not going to next row in main class.